# Android Prevent Screen From Turning Off

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, screen

So I saw that you can make an xml that does LinearLayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:keepScreenOn="true">
</LinearLayout>
```

My question is: I am doing a jQuery Mobile app, and I thought I could just put this in my web.xml file.  However, I keep getting errors when I try to do so.  Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Is there an easier way to make it so my Android tablet will not turn off the screen while I am in the web application?  Like I said, I tried just putting the LinearLayout code into my web.xml, and it gave me a ton of errors.  Thanks.

Comment: LinearLayout is for android layout files, not for server side web.xml files.

Are you trying to find code to put into a web page that tells the browser not to let the phone turn off?

Comment: That was the idea. They will be using a Bluetooth scanner to scan barcodes, and it works fine currently.  However, the app doesn't recognize the scanning as actual screen activity, since they are not touching it, so it turns off after about a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an easier way to make it so my Android tablet will not turn off the screen while I am in the web application?

It is not possible. In fact, it would be seriously disturbing if an arbitrary Web site could affect a device that way.

If you elect to create a native app, or perhaps even a PhoneGap app, then you can consider trying to control whether or not the screen turns off.

Comment: Javascript code can be interfaced from your native mobile application, that is the only way I know that can make a webpage interact with the device.

Comment: I just decided to adjust the setting for sleep time on the device itself. We provide all the tablets, and Surefox locks them out of everything else, so it's easier to just do that. Thanks though for the help.